# Animation on nested component isn't firing

Tags: angular, angular-animations

Here is my component template:

```
<div 
    *ngIf="modalQueue[0]"
    class="backdrop"
    [@backdropAnim]>
    <app-modal
        [modalData]="modalQueue[0]"
        (modalComplete)="onModalComplete()"
        [@modalAnim]>
    </app-modal>
</div>
```

Here is my animation setup:

```js
animations: [
    trigger('backdropAnim', [
      state('void', style({
        opacity: 0
      })),
      transition('void <=> *', [
        animate('0.2s ease')
      ])
    ]),
    trigger('modalAnim', [
      state('void', style({
        transform: 'rotateX(-10deg) translateY(30px)',
      })),
      transition('void <=> *', [
        animate('0.2s ease')
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
```

The idea is the backdrop and by extension the modal will fade in from opacity 0,
And the modal itself will rotate up slightly for effect.

Everything (other than the backdrop fade animation) works fine if I delete `[@backdropAnim]` from the template. I'm guessing it has something to do with the order of operations with the `*ngIf` ?

If it's the `*ngIf` then why does removing the first animation trigger make the second work?

Comment: Seems to be working,,, are you able to reproduce this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8dbp5a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @OwenKelvin I'm not seeing it work on your example either, the modal animates opacity but it doesn't rotate or transform at all.